# Inequality between angles with respect to different inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, angle

Given a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ with two inner products $\langle,\rangle_g$ and $\langle,\rangle_{\tilde{g}}$, what are the inequalities for angles between vectors? Is there a similar inequality as for norms like
\begin{align}
a\lVert v\rVert_g\leq\lVert v\rVert_{\tilde{g}} \leq b\lVert v\rVert_g\,?
\end{align}
For instance, I'm looking for something like 
\begin{align}
a \theta(v,w)\leq \tilde\theta(v,w)\leq b\theta(v,w)\,,
\end{align}
where $v,w\in V$ and $\theta(v,w)$ is the angle between the two vectors with respect to the inner product $g$ and $\tilde\theta(v,w)$ is the angle between the two vectors with respect to the inner product $\tilde g$.

This should be some standard knowledge, but I don't know a reference where this is shown/discussed. Does anybody have a tip for me?

Comment: if $f(v) = \lVert v\rVert^2$ then $\langle v,w \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( f(v+w) - f(v) - f(w) \right)$

Comment: Might give better results to use $\frac{1}{4} \left( f(v+w) - f(v-w) \right),$ two vectors instead of three.

Comment: finally, I do not yet see your desired inequality in the original question, but I think it uses the stronger property that, fixing one norm, the ratio of the other norm to it is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Given two positive definite quadratic forms $g$ and $\tilde g$ on the real vector space ${\mathbb R}^2$ there is always a basis that diagonalizes both simultaneously. Therefore we may assume
$$[g]=\left[\matrix{1&0\cr 0&1\cr}\right],\qquad [\tilde g]=\left[\matrix{\lambda&0\cr 0&\mu\cr}\right]$$
with $\lambda$, $\mu>0$. If it is only about angles you may even assume $\lambda\mu=1$, or something similar that suits your needs.

Using this setup it should not be too difficult to compute the maximal angle distortion in terms of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, and then universally. Unfortunately there is no universal upper bound.

Comment: This was helpful. I also found this very helpful post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205099/how-does-cosine-similarity-change-after-a-linear-transformation. Based on this, I believe that the bounds that I was looking for are given by $\frac{1-\lambda^2\tan^2{\theta}}{1+\lambda^2\tan^2{\theta}} \leq\cos{\tilde\theta} \leq \frac{1-\lambda^{-2}\tan^2{\theta}}{1+\lambda^{-2}\tan^2{\theta}}$ where $\lambda=b/a$ from the norm inequality. This inequality should at least hold for small angles.